# How do I update my data when calling a computed property from a method?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I used to have a huge template that consisted of multiple list items, each with their own conditions related to specific objects.
I decided it would be easier to store all the links in an array and move the conditions into methods instead.
The problem now is that some of the list items use computed properties which handles data from a prop, and when I used v-if these would change immediately when the data got updated, but now that I am using a method to call the computed property, the condition is not changed.

How do I make the component update without using v-if?

This is an example of how some of my code is written:

```
    <template v-for="(item, index) in rentalContract">
      <li :key="index" v-if="(index < 5 || showListItem) && item.function != null">
        <i :class="item.iconClass"></i>
        {{ item.name }}
        <strong class="ml-2"> {{ item.function }} </strong>
      </li>
    </template>

<script>
    props: {
      tenants: Array,
    },
data() {
      return {
        showListItem: false,
        rentalContract: [
          {
            iconClass: "fas fa-user fa-fw fa-lg icon-class ml-2 mr-2",
            name: this.$t('subtenantInUnit'),
            function: this.subtenantInUnit()
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      subtenantPresent() {
        return this.tenants.some(tenant => tenant.subtenant)
      }
    },
    methods: {
      subtenantInUnit(){
        if(this.subtenantPresent){
          return this.$t('yes')
        } else {
          return this.$t('no')
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Even if the condition is True and the console shows "True", the function still returns False.
I tried to fix this by re-writing the function like this:

```
  subtenantInUnit(){
    if(this.tenants.some(tenant => tenant.subtenant)){
      return this.$t('yes')
    } else {
      return this.$t('no')
    }
  }
```

This actually works, BUT it does not update automatically like it did when I used v-if="subtenant".
I need to refresh the page in order to see the changes.
Is there a way I can force the component to refresh when the condition is changed, or is there some other way to mimic v-if and only use the computed property?

Remember I cannot write a v-if for this in my template because there will be other list items which should not be affected by the conditions of this one item.

Comment: Wouldn't it keep your reactivity if you set the method subtenantInUnit() to be computed property as well?

Comment: I tried that, but if I put that in computed, I get the error "TypeError: this.subtenantInUnit is not a function"

Comment: That comes out from data: function: this.subtenantInUnit(). Just remove parentheses there. Like this:  function: this.subtenantInUnit